Powershell Group By Count Greater Than 99,999
Get-Childitem "C:\MyFolder" -Recurse -File | Group Extension -NoElement | Sort Count -Desc 

This command returns results in this format
Count Name                     
----- ----                     
...62 .PNG
...50 .JPG                     
77305 .pdf                     
72457 .msg    

Is there any way to show the full count regardless of the number of files?

Format-Table -AutoSize but then your output is no longer usable.

@SantiagoSquarzon It worked, why do you say the output is no longer usable?

when objects are passed thru Format-Table they are no longer the same object, a new "formatting" object is created from that input.
